# Remove Font Scaling — Font Manager Settings Changed Font Appearance

Tags: 22.04, fonts, font-manager

I think I must have changed a wrong setting in [Font Manager](http://fontmanager.github.io/): all the system fonts suddenly changed appearance. Before, they were normal, and now they are pixelated and squarish.

[Text is pixelated and squarish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzjR4.png)

I think I must have changed a setting in Font Manager, because it was about then that I noticed it (and I think I would notice right away). My guess is I shouldn't have messed with the "Text Scaling Factor". I would have thought, though, that changing it back to 1.0 would fix it, and it hasn't. Fonts in the browser and other apps are not affected, but window titles, the terminal, and all the places controlled by the OS are.

[Text Scaling Factor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eli9i.png)

Please help! It's really distracting and difficult to read. And I'm out of ideas.

I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, 64-bit, Gnome 42.9, and X11 windowing system.

Comment: Are you possibly using a custom font in `gnome-terminal` preferences?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson I am using Ubuntu Mono for the terminal font. But the terminal was not like this before, and this has changed the appearance other places, including the time at the top, the battery percentage, and window titles. Unless you don't mean the terminal `Preferences`.

Comment: Yes, I mean the terminal Preferences. Basically I wondered if "Custom font" is checked. If not, I really can't tell what the problem is.